# To put something in service of, or in lower priority to

Tags: idiom-requests

I'm looking for a slick way of saying a person is able to override their ego, or place their ego in the service of a higher goal. For example "He is able to subvert his ego for the needs of the team", but that seems a bit awkward to me.  Any better ideas?

Comment: I think the idea you have in mind is _subordinate_ (to make subject or subservient ," according to Merriam-Webster), not _subvert_ (to overturn or overthrow from the foundations: RUIN"). But _subordinate_ normally takes the preposition _to_, not _for_. So the sentence would read, "He is able to subordinate his ego to the needs of the team." But this suggestion is simply a word choice recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

You could try rearranging the order:

> He is able to put the needs of the team ahead of his ego.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that "He is able to [sacrifice](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sacrifice) his needs for those of his team."

> 3. the surrender or destruction of something prized or desirable for the sake of something considered as having a higher or more pressing claim.